# Teradata Sql Assistant not showing text in the query result view

Tags: sql, select, teradata, informix, dbeaver

When I run a select query on an informix database using Teradata Sql Assistant all the text fields are null. But when I use another database manager like DBeaver, using a select query on the same table, I get values in the text fields. Has anyone else encountered this issue? if yes, how did you fixed it?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues today, try converting the text column to varchar in your select.

```
SELECT CAST(txt_column As VARCHAR(8000))
```